# Кость не привязалась к объекту

Tags: анимация, blender

Хочу сделать анимацию для лука, на базу лука кости прикрепились могу поворавивать и т.д., а к тетиве нет (Лук и тетива один объект)

[image: Данная кость не работает]

Answer (score 1):

Object View. Надо выбрать мэш(mesh) лука и зажав shift выбрать кости, далее необходимо указать родителя (Set Parent, Ctrl+P) и внутри Armature Deform выбрать With Automatic Weights.

[image: Ctrl+P]